# Why is 'estoy' used when saying "I'm related to"

Tags: gramática, cópulas

I understand

> I'm related to David, he's my grandad.

translates as

> Estoy relacionado con David, él es mi abuelo.

Why is *estoy* used and not *soy*?

It seems to me that the relationship is permanent and defining, so I would expect *soy* to be used.

Comment: "Estoy relacionado con" for a relative relationship sounds a bit weird. I's more common to say it as "Soy familiar/pariente de David, él es mi padre", or "Estoy emparentado con David, él es mi padre" is very common. So there's the same problem with "emparentado" for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Javi mentioned, a better translation is:

> Estoy emparentado con David.

When to use `ser` vs. `estar` is always difficult for foreign speakers. While the rule of thumb is that `ser` is used for something permanent, there are many exceptions that you'll just have to learn using the language.

That said: what about inlaws? That relationship is not necessarily permanent.

Comment: So with _emparentado_ you always use estar? I guess all relationships could be considered temporary if you factor in death.

Comment: Yes, it's always estar. Not sure about the philosophical explanation :-) However, you use *ser* to state all specific relationships, biological or not (*ella es mi suegra*)

Comment: I'm not sure about it either! :)

Comment: Don't forget that it is *estar emparentado* but *soy pariente*; same root, different verb. You cannot assume that the difference between *ser* and *estar* lies always in permanence vs. transience.

Comment: It's more complex than that. *Es mi mujer* but *está casada conmigo*; they describe the same relationship using different verbs.

Comment: One helpful rule that applies in the case of "Ella es mi suegra/hermana/hija" and "Es mi esposa" is that if the subject and predicate are both nouns (or pronouns), then ser will be used instead of estar.  This rule is very helpful because it can be applied in many situations when deciding about ser and estar.

Answer (score 3):

As comments state, permanence is not always the key to choose between ser and estar.

When combined with the past participle of a verb, "ser" creates a simple passive, "estar" expresses the state.

So e.g.:

> Ser casado = Get married, to enter into marriage
>   Estar casado = Be married, to be in a marriage

This should explain why you need "estoy" in your example.

Answer (score -2):

The explanation is simple. SER is "To be" and when this verb is used we usually are talking about ourselves. The most used form of the phrase you are explaining is "Soy el hijo de David" in which you can see the I am very well specified. ESTAR (also "To be") is mostly used as a verb of staying in, meaning, a continuous action and mostly used for others. Though "Estoy Emparentado con..." is a correct way of saying it, "Soy Pariente de..." is the most widely used. Might be related to the humans egocentric phenomenom and definetly states possession of the other in a way. Philosophically examining it. 
   Now, we usually don't even use it that way either in spanish, we tend to say "David es mi padre" or "Es mi padre" because is more correct to mention the other before us which subconsciously shows humbleness.